# Create SHA1 hash of int32 list with elements bigger than 255

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, hash

I have an int32 list of size 10 with elements that are bigger than 255. E.g. `lst = [21443324, 435654454, 3242234, ..., 434343623]`. How can I get the SHA1 hash of that list?

```
hash1 = hashlib.sha1(bytearray(lst))
```

obviously does not work, since the values of `lst` would need to be in range (0,255).

Comment: Break your integers into bytes.

Comment: Depends on how you want to transform your int32 numbers to bytes, taking into account [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Answer (score 0):

Use `struct.pack`. For big-endian int32, use:

```
endianness = '>'
b = struct.pack(f'{endianness}{len(lst)}I', *lst)
hash1 = hashlib.sha1(b)
```

For little-endian int32, use `endianness = '<'`.

If you want to use the lowest byte only of each int32, use

```
hash1 = hashlib.sha1(bytes(x & 0xff for x in lst))
```

Answer (score -1):

**I hope this helps:**

```
hash1 = hashlib.sha1(bytearray(b"[21443324, 435654454, 3242234, 52158998, 54587878, 12123623, 54215525,  434343623, 54888787, 65966427]"))
```

**Output:**

```
<sha1 _hashlib.HASH object @ 0x0000023A66AD6810>
```

Comment: That's the hash of the ASCII/byte string representing those numbers (and some python list brackets, commas and whitespace), not the numbers themselves.

Answer (score -1):

**How about this:**

```
def hash_func(r):
    p = str(r)
    return hash(p)


hash_func([21443324, 435654454, 3242234, 52158998, 54587878, 12123623, 54215525,  434343623, 54888787, 65966427])
```

**Output:**

```
870403843331539247
```

Comment: That's the [hash value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hash) (likely not SHA1) of the string representation of the list.